# Add picture to Java GUI at specific path

Tags: java, user-interface, directory, src

I need to add 3 pictures to my code . 
At the moment those 3 pictures are not at the SRC folder , but outside of it - I'm talking
about Eclipse Project .

Here is my code :

```
Image myImage = new Image(null, "treasure1.jpg");

while (iterator.hasNext())
{

    String current = iterator.next();   // get an original room in the maze
    Coordinate mazeDot = null;
    if (this.m_rooms.containsKey(current))   // if the string key exists 
        {
            mazeDot = this.m_rooms.get(current);  // get the coordinate of that specific room as two Ints
            e.gc.drawImage(myImage,mazeDot.getXCoordinate(),mazeDot.getYCoordinate());
        }                   
}
```

But I want to put that picture ( `treasure1.jpg` ) in the `src` folder of my project .
I've tried this code :

```
Image myImage = new Image(null, "src/treasure1.jpg");
```

but it didn't work , but compiled (after I put the picture in the `src` folder).
The src is in lower case .

Any ideas what's wrong  ?

Regards,
Ron

Comment: What image class are you using there? There's is no constructor on java.awt.Image like you've shown in your code.

Comment: I'm using no class , just the Image tool. But it doesn't work well when I put the files in the "src" folder .. no idea why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you image is now part of your packages hierarchy. So you should be able to access it using the following snippet:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(path))
```

where path is either a relative path to your image from the package in which your class is located, or the complete path starting at the root package, i.e:

```
Relative: ressources/images/treasure1.jpg
Absolute: /org/you/ressources/images/treasure1.jpg
```

Or, if your image is in the same package as your class, just use the name of the image. You can also use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) instead of Toolkit as far as I know.

Comment: I was going to write a similar post; This solution is much better because it's bad practice to deal with absolute path names(like `src`). Additionally, this code will continue to work after packaging the application in a JAR.

Comment: I'll tell you to truth , guys , I need to send my assignment to the lecturer to get my grade , but he works only with SRC ... :)

Comment: Here is a look of my current folder http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/mycurrentfolder.gif/ ......

Comment: What is not working now that you have a tips on how to access an image located in one of your package ?